# what value of x is required to exit through eof-object? scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define (number-checker)
     (define userinput (read))
     (cond
        [(eof-object? userinput) print-fun)]
        [else
          (set!  tries (+ 1 userinput))
          (number-checker)]))
```

If i want to quit the program what would i have to write in order for program to go to print-fun?

Comment: I don't remember "[" in the syntax...

Comment: uhm  it's scheme? [ is for if/cond statement

Comment: are you [*sure*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/r4rs/r4rs_6.html) ?

Comment: yes i am sure i wrote all of my previous code with [] syntax and it works fine

Comment: are you using PLT scheme ? rocket ? dr scheme ?

Comment: i just want to know what user need to put as userinput in order to make (eof-object? userinput) true to execute print-fun

Comment: @alfasin: `[]` *is* Scheme -- since R6Rs.

Comment: @EliBarzilay damn... My last experience was in BGU in 2005 during the second degree, I guess things have changed since then...

Comment: @alfasin: Well, in 2005 square brackets were still unspecified, R6RS is from 2007.  But in Racket (which was called PLT Scheme then) they were used for ages.  (BTW, my first experience with Scheme was also from BGU, but a bit earlier -- around 1992...)

Comment: @alfasin If you want the printfun to run, use (printfun).

Comment: @soegaard what is `printfun` ? is that a new command in scheme ? I assumed that the intention was to print either "fun" or "print-fun" on exit, this is why I changed it to `'print-fun`

Comment: @alfasin Well, since the original asker reads a number, I am guessing that he wants to print some kind of response to the user. He names this function printfun (there is not builtin function of that name).

Comment: @soegaard that's what I thought too. so probably it would look better if I changed `'print-fun` to `'fun`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not compiling for me (using Racket):

also after fixing the typo:

[image]

If I understand correctly it's supposed to read the user-input from prompt and bail-out when the "end of file" character arrives. But, this code will definitely won't work. what is `print-fun` ? etc.

**UPDATE:**
The working code is:

```
#lang racket
(define (number-checker)
     (define userinput (read))
     (define tries 'a)
     (cond
        [(eof-object? userinput) 'print-fun]
        [else
          (set!  tries (+ 1 userinput))
          (number-checker)]))
```

It works like this:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
another screenshot that shows the eof button that appears after you run `(number-checker)`:

[image]

Comment: i just that was my typo O.o do you know what i have to put as userinput inorder for eof-obejct to be true? i can't test my code cuz of that

Comment: uhm  idk how to post pic... but it compiles on mine trust me. can you just answer my question? T.T btw u forgot #lang racket

Comment: I updated my answer, but still, even if I call `#lang racket` i get `expand: unbound identifier in module in: print-fun` and if I change `print-fun` to `'print-fun` (which probably was the meaning) I'll get `set!: unbound identifier in module in: tries` etc.

Comment: urg im not allowed to post pic? darn it forgot my old acc password and email...but i can assure you it does work on mine I'm 100% sure it work....(read) reads user's input

Comment: im guessing im using different racket platform then you are.. this was how i learned and did all of my assignment for past few months

Comment: O.o this was what i was trying to do...what did u enter to get 'print-fun?

Comment: check-out the last screenshot attached

Comment: OMG...that was what i was trying to figure and it was there T.T i thought im suppose to enter some kind of value in there Thanks for the helppppp! :D

Comment: service is my middle name :))) (kidding) good luck with scheme - it's a beautiful language!!!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is really not very clear, but if you just want to ask how to get a value that [`eof-object?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-ops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eof-object~3f%29%29) will be happy with, then you can use [`eof`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-ops.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._eof%29%29).

Comment: idk how to make it more clear... what should userinput be inorder for (eof-object? userinput) to be true?

Comment: @user1516649: `eof` is the name you'd use if you wanted to write the code; but when you're reading stuff in DrRacket then like @alfasin showed, you'd use the "eof" button; and on a linux/osx console you'd type `Ctrl+D`.